# Domain name with trailing dot in Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

Is it not possible to add a site to Google Webmasters Tools with a trailing dot in the domain name?

Like for example, `http://example.com./`?

If I add it, it becomes `http://example.com/`, were the trailing dot is removed. And therefore the sitemap fails because 301.

Comment: I'm curious, why are you utilizing the trailing dot on your domain name?

Comment: What would be the point of forcing a trailing dot? Yes it follows standards set in DNS notation, but the trailing dot was never intended to be a real part of the address. Trust me. I was there when ARPA-Net was written and wrote some limited router code myself. It was never a consideration.

Comment: Just for science (and ignorance), and i got in sock after visitng http://info.cern.ch./hypertext/TBL_Disclaimer.html by following a link from Tim Berners-Lee, i mean, he can't be wrong at writing href's.

well, turns out that google webmaster tools as well as many other applications doesn't correctly handly FQDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, turns out that google webmaster tools as well as many other applications doesn't correctly handly FQDN, and just apply a redirect (some browsers) or just ignore it and work with the ambiguous domain name directly (some apps).

to force them to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Googlebot.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^example\.com$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com$1  [R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Googlebot.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^example\.com\.$       [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com.$1  [R=301,NE]
```

Please read closetnoc comment above if you plan to apply this dirty rules in your machine.

Comment: also, an evil range of apps try to validate the domain before work with it, and FQDN fail the validation even without taking care if is really working or not.

Comment: Since it's a "dirty rule", and your reference said it's not appropriate to use it that way, how can you claim GWT and other apps are doing it wrong?

Comment: Because they fail in establish the connection even if the server has no problem in reply to a given request.